# creating a dynamic array from the response GET from a database on a remote server

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have requested and received a table of data from the database on the remote server such as below:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"First news title","text":"First news text", "image":"../images/pic1.jpg"},
{"id":2,"title":"This is the second header","text":"a line of text","image":"../images/pic2.jpg"}]
```

The data that i actually got is even more. What I would want is that I create a dynamic array that gives me the array of data that I sent as a request to the database. Is that possible?

```
onLoad:function(options){
  var self=this;
  wx.request({
    url: 'http://108.61.200.138:8081/News',
    data: {
          },
    method: 'GET', 
    header: {
      'content-type':'application/json'
    },
    success: function(res){
      self.setData({
      })
      console.log(res)
    }
  })
}
```

The above code is used in an application developer tool from Wechat. The data is requested from the link through get method while the results(the data retrieved) is shown at success. Then the data is set to sync for the applet by allowing the data of the page to sync with the data from the database. The above is all currently done by hardcoding which means that i manually set how many data to be synced and so on. what i need is to write the code in a way that i give a value and the data array retrieved is sliced to that exact value and allows it to be synced.

Comment: I think we need a little more info, please provide code examples. Also, what's your definition of **dynamic array**?

Comment: I am still experimenting which failed...
What i actually wanted is that when i load a page on an applet, the applet sends a request out through its API which retrieves the data table from a database on a remote server. what i wanted to do is that write a code so that the applet can choose on it's own to choose how much rows of the array that it wanted and being able to display it or something like that